# Default Date set is not working Angular js Dirctives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datetimepicker

I want to set some default date in my particular id in HTML element,
Now I using datetimepicker in angular js directives I have to get the date from the datetimepicker but could not set the default date in my id.

```
timeTracker.directive('datetimepicker', function($parse) {
    var date = new Date();
    var newdate = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datetimepicker({
                format: "DD-MM-YYYY",
                defaultDate: new Date(newdate),
                maxDate:new Date(),
            }).on('dp.change', function(e) {
                var Reportdate = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
                Reportdate.assign(scope, e.target.value);
                scope.ReportModel.Reportdate = e.target.value;
                scope.$apply()
            })
        }
    };

});
```

I want to set some default date in my HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

I have created daterangepicker directive, refer below link

```
https://jsfiddle.net/Nathash/0zcuxm02/5/
```

- Handles datetime picker (plugin used is `http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/`)
- takes options input
- invokes callback function after selecting date/time